# iOS : Could not build module <framework-name>

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, module, frameworks

I've got Library from another team. I'm trying to use library in our project and while do so getting an error **Could not build module 'Common Library' (name of framework)**

[image: Screenshot 1]

Below are solutions that I worked on but didn't helped :

```
1. Delete Derived data content. Clean and Build.

2. Framework is added in 'Link binary with libraries' of Build phases.

3. While adding framework checkmarked : Target and Copy content to folder.
```

Even I tried this [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620786/import-causes-parse-issue-could-not-build-module) but didn't got any break-through!

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

The only thing that worked was deleting `Objective-C bridging header path` in `Swift compiler - code generation section` of `build settings` in Project.

However, thereafter I'm not able to get Common interface to create instance (i.e. Common dosen't appears in drop-down list)

Below is framework structure.

[image: Screenshot 6]

Any other fix?

Comment: check this it may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620786/import-causes-parse-issue-could-not-build-module

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman : Didn't helped. :-(

Comment: Can you try to delete import line and rewrite it again if it does not work then use @import instead of #import . Actually I faced same issue while building xmppframework in my app so I deleted the line and then write import again then it worked

Comment: @import will be followed by Framework name without any quotes and <> brackets. So there is no question of using @ instead of #

Comment: So you have source codes & project file of CommonLibrary, is it right? Can you show me the project tree of your workspace?

Comment: @HarrisonXi : Source code and project file for CommonLibrary is correct and it has been throughly tested by Client. Due to confidentiality I cannot share it.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey I want to know the project structure but not the source codes. Just let me know how do you put CommonLibrary project into LibraryTester project (or worksapce).

Comment: @HarrisonXi : I've updated question with Framework structure. Check and if there is any solution let me know.

Answer (score 10):

you can try delete **DerivedData** dir.

where is DerivedData?(xcode 8)

go to File > workspace Settings, you'll see DerivedData path.

[DerivedData path in xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/1528524)

[image][image]

Comment: Didn't worked this one...I tried it at the beginning.

Comment: The problem cause by cocoaspod version, there will be a solution.

Comment: set **Build Active Architecture Only** ***NO*** about targets and project and pods.

Comment: @lingyfh Your solution not work

Answer (score 3):

I think you does not need to compile CommonLibrary.framework again. So you can try to remove it from **Embedded Binaries** list. And make sure the path of CommonLibrary.framework is in your **Framework Search Paths**.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the framework you are integrating is supporting your project architecture.

To see the framework supported architecture, use Terminal and navigate to Framework folder.

use, "lipo -info myFramework.framework/MyFramework"

And, if you want to use the framework files in your project, check whether the files are available in Framework/Headers Folder.

Getting this error :

[image: Screenshot]

Try, "file myFramework.framework/MyFramework" in Terminal

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem:
1. My 'GoodLuck' framework had two headers: GoodLuck.h and GLAdder.h
2. Project which import this framework couldn't compile

Solution:
Import GLAdder.h in GoodLuck.h, rebuild the framework. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, due to a typo in my GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS, which therefore invalidated all of my code.

First helpful warning was multiple "Macro Name must be an identifier" followed by multiple "Could not build module" messages.

Answer (score 1):

As this question do not have answer yet, so adding my answer here it may help in future for some another developer.

I know due to privacy you can not disclose the details.

I have used same library and faced same issue so just did did this two things it is working fine.

1. In General -> Frameworks,Libraries -> CommonLibrary.framework just select that and choose -> Embed Without Signing.
2. Build Settings -> Search for "workspace" -> Validate workspace -> set it NO

That's it you are done.